# Spark tasks blockes randomly on standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

We are having a quite complex application that runs on Spark Standalone. 
In some cases the tasks from one of the workers blocks randomly for an infinite amount of time in the RUNNING state.

[image: Blocked tasks]

Extra info:

- there aren't any errors in the logs
- ran with logger in debug and i didn't saw any relevant messages (i see when the tasks starts but then there is not activity for it)
- the jobs are working ok if i have just only 1 worker
- the same job may execute the second time without any issues, in a proper amount of time
- i don't have any really big partitions that could  cause delays for some of the tasks.
- in spark 2.0 i've moved from RDD to Datasets and i have the same issue
- in spark 1.4 i was able to overcome the issue by turning on speculation, but in spark 2.0 the blocking tasks are from different workers (while in 1.4 i have blocking tasks on only 1 worker) so speculation isn't fixing my issue.
- i have the issue on more environments so i don't think it's hardware related.

Did anyone experienced something similar? Any suggestions on how could i identify the issue?

Thanks a lot!

**Later Edit:** I think i'm facing the same issue described here: [Spark Indefinite Waiting with "Asked to send map output locations for shuffle"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600993/spark-indefinite-waiting-with-asked-to-send-map-output-locations-for-shuffle) and here: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-stalling-during-shuffle-maybe-a-memory-issue-td6067.html but both are without a working solution.

The last thing in the log repeated infinitely is: [dispatcher-event-loop-18] DEBUG org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl - parentName: , name: TaskSet_2, runningTasks: 6

Comment: 1) Could you extract some code that actually blocks? 2) Did you check GC logs 3) Are you using some form of thread locking/In-house multithreading?

Comment: 1) The application is quite complex and i couldn't find the actual part that is causing the block. 2) No issue in the logs. Even if it was an gc/memory issues it would behave similar for the same job. Now the same job finish almost all the times in a few seconds but randomly it blocks. 3) No other form of multithreading/locking mechanism are used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed for me by allocating just one core per executor. If I have executors with more then 1 core the issue appears again. I didn't yet understood why is this happening but for the ones having similar issue they can try this.